# unable to obtain a class label in weka java *WEKA*DUMMY*STRING*FOR*STRING*ATTRIBUTES*

Tags: java, model, weka

I am trying to classify an instance in java using the weka library and the tutorials online.

I have built a model in my device and loaded that model from the disk using this code.

```
public void makeModel() throws Exception
    {
        ArffLoader loader = new ArffLoader();
    loader.setFile(new File("data.arff"));

   Instances structure = loader.getDataSet();
    structure.setClassIndex(1);

// train NaiveBayes

NaiveBayesMultinomial n = new NaiveBayesMultinomial();
FilteredClassifier f = new FilteredClassifier();
StringToWordVector s = new StringToWordVector();

s.setUseStoplist(true);
s.setWordsToKeep(100);

f.setFilter(s);

f.setClassifier(n);
structure.numAttributes();
 f.buildClassifier(structure);
Instance current;


Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(structure);
 eval.crossValidateModel(f, structure, 10, new Random(1));
 System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n======\n", false));



// output generated model
//System.out.println(f);
 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                            new FileOutputStream("classifier.model"));
 oos.writeObject(f);
 oos.flush();
 oos.close();
    }
```

------------------------ Output-------------

## Results

Correctly Classified Instances       20158               79.6948 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances      5136               20.3052 %
Kappa statistic                          0.6737
Mean absolute error                      0.0726
Root mean squared error                  0.2025
Relative absolute error                 38.7564 %
Root relative squared error             66.1815 %
Coverage of cases (0.95 level)          96.4142 %
Mean rel. region size (0.95 level)      27.7531 %
Total Number of Instances            25294

---

Then i used the same model to classify an unlabelled instance.

```
public void classify() throws Exception
    {
        FilteredClassifier cls = (FilteredClassifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("classifier.model");


Instances unlabeled = new Instances(
                         new BufferedReader(
                           new FileReader("test.arff")));

 // set class attribute
 unlabeled.setClassIndex(0);

 // create copy
 Instances labeled = new Instances(unlabeled);

 // label instances
 for (int i = 0; i < unlabeled.numInstances(); i++) {
     System.out.println(labeled.instance(i).classValue());
     System.out.print(", actual: " + labeled.classAttribute().value((int)labeled.instance(i).classValue()));
   double clsLabel = cls.classifyInstance(unlabeled.instance(i));
   labeled.instance(i).setClassValue(clsLabel);
   System.out.println(", predicted: " + labeled.classAttribute().value((int) clsLabel));
 }
 // save labeled data
System.out.println("ended");


    }
```

------------------------ Output---------------------------

1.0
, actual: Bud1? is a This is a new new string.txtIlocblobR(?????? @? @? @? @E?DSDB ` @? @? @, predicted: *WEKA*DUMMY*STRING*FOR*STRING*ATTRIBUTES*
2.0
, actual: This is a new new string 
, predicted: *WEKA*DUMMY*STRING*FOR*STRING*ATTRIBUTES*
ended

---

However, my error is that the predicted is actually ***WEKA*DUMMY*STRING*FOR*STRING*ATTRIBUTES*** when it should have given me a class label instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While saving classifier also save Instances (just header, no data required):

```
Instances instancesSample = new Instances(structure, 0);
instancesSample.setClassIndex(1);
...
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream("classifier.model"));
oos.writeObject(f);
oos.writeObject(instancesSample);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
```

After model is loaded, load saved Instances as `instancesSample`.
While classifying:

```
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("classifier.model")));
FilteredClassifier cls = (FilteredClassifier)= (Classifier) objectInputStream.readObject();
Instances instancesSample = (Instances) objectInputStream.readObject();
objectInputStream.close();

int classIndex = 1;
Instances ins = unlabeled[i];
double clsLabel = cls.classifyInstance(ins);
String prediction = instancesSample.attribute(classIndex).value((int) clsLabel));
System.out.println(", predicted: " + prediction);
```

Comment: hi sorry but i don't really understand the part about loading from previously saved file? Which file are you referring to?

Comment: You are saving your model file to classifier.model. Likewise save `Instances structure` to file. Thats what I'm referring.

Answer (score 0):

I have added these lines to my classify method.

```
ArffLoader loader = new ArffLoader();
    loader.setFile(new File("data.arff"));

   Instances structure = loader.getDataSet();
    structure.setClassIndex(1);
```

To obtain the class label i changed it to this

```
System.out.println(", predicted: " + structure.classAttribute().value((int) clsLabel));
```